# Loading a single javascript file from multiple files

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to load a single javascript in pieces by calling the javascript from external separate files, and was wondering the best way to go about doing this. Specifically, this is a just a basic google maps page, and I want to organize the code a little better. I'm hoping to split the marker variables up into groups and store those groups of variables in separate files, then call those files within the main javascript header of the page. I want to restrict this code to just html and javascript to maintan its simplicity for the purpose of future updates by individuals less than knowledgeable in this area. I don't do a whole lot of coding with JavaScript so, if there already is a built-in function for this, that would be great. This is purely aesthetic, just to make the code a little cleaner. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I should probably be a little more specific. The groups of marker variables are within the function that initializes and populates the google map. I would like to store those markers externally and call them back into that function. I'd also like to do this without any outside frameworks or api's. Different people will need to edit different groups to add markers in the future. That's why I'm going to call these externally. This makes it easier for people to locate the group they're going to add to, instead of having to look through the entire page of markers to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you don't want to call one JavaScript files from several another JavaScript files. You want just save some groups of variables. Well, you can save it - with a server-side database or, may be, with http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/ or http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Comment: You are correct. Do you know anyway to do this without a server? This won't actually be a live page, and so it won't be accessed via a server. This is basically just going to be a maps application that will be ran completely locally. That's why this needs to be a simple as possible. I can understand if there's no way to do this considering the situation, as I can't personally think of a way to do this within my limiting parameters.

Comment: As i said, you can use WebStorage, or IndexedDB, or, may be, [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Comment: May be, you will found that [lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add references to external files:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGradient.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xpath.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kml2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"> ... </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ....
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: These aren't separate script files, rather groups of variables within one js script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a "feature loading" and/or "on-demand javascript loading" framework.  Since you're trying to use Google maps, I would recommend you use the [Google Loader API](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/)  which works very closely to what you're seeking.

for example: With a simply JS you can do the following....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("search", "1");
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>
```

... and it will load the multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up you code for your development is a good idea. There for, there are a lot of frameworks to help you organize your code with the help of MVC and psudo MVC models.

Try:

http://maccman.github.com/spine/

or

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

But what prevents you from having everything in one file on the production environment?
Its easier on the server requests. And you want to integrate this in your build process anyway...

But if you insist in on adding them to the DOM you can do this of course:

```
document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="yourfile.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))
```

this will add

```
<script src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

to your dom

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to split up a single script into multiple .js files. As far as I know, this should work fine as long as you include a  tag to load each file. You may need to load the files in order (i.e. don't include a file that calls a function that has not been difeined yet).

However, be aware that splitting up your script will result in more calls to the server, which will slow down page load. In most cases, just including a few scripts won't even make a noticible difference in load time.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing this? Like I said before, I'm nothing near a JS guru.

Comment: I was referring to what Cheeso suggested.
Based on the update to your question, I'm not sure if this is what you want to do.